# Compare variable with older of two other variables from list using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

This part of code I wrote for advanced search by deadline of Cases.

```
var temp = (from j in db.Get_AllCases(user_id, true, -1) select j).ToList();
temp =  (from c in temp 
           where (
           (String.IsNullOrEmpty(deadline) || c.Deadline <= System.Convert.ToDateTime(deadline))                     
           ) 
           select c).ToList();
```

Some Cases has extended deadline and that is my problem because in that case end of Cases is not deadline than extend_deadline. In this case line from above code

```
(String.IsNullOrEmpty(deadline) || c.Deadline <= System.Convert.ToDateTime(deadline))
```

has to look like this

```
(String.IsNullOrEmpty(extend_deadline) || c.Deadline <= System.Convert.ToDateTime(deadline))
```

How can I modify statement for temp variable that could include this exception. Deadline and extend_deadline are two columns in database table and for search it is very important for me to compare chosen date with older of deadline and extend_deadline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
temp = (from c in temp
        let maxDate = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.ExtendedDealine)) ? c.Deadline : c.ExtendedDealine
        where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(maxDate) || Convert.ToDateTime(maxDate) <= System.Convert.ToDateTime(deadline))
        select c).ToList();
```

On a side note, you should use `DateTime` instead of converting string all the time.

Comment: I test your code when set ExtendedDeadline to 15.03.2013 and set Deadline to 13.03.2013 but in that case maxDate is 13.03.2013 but I want 15.03.2013

Comment: Well, that's not what the condition there says: `if ExtendedDeadline is empty, use Deadline, else use ExtendedDeadline`. Also, I just ran this code with mock data. It works fine. Are you sure you've set the variables correctly?

Comment: This code is suitable for me: `let maxDate = c.ExtendedDeadline > c.Deadline ? c.ExtendedDeadline : c.Deadline`, your idea is great and thank you very much